# Finding selected parsed data via onClickListener for switching Play&Pause Button

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-json

I am developing an App that stores ringtone .. I update the contents for new ringtones from mysql database..
I am trying to create a play and pause switch button ..
now my problem is i can't find the exact selected item .. 
[this is a PICTURE off what i am doing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucUhg.jpg)

As i showed you by arrow , when i click to every play button just the first one starts ..

This is The Code so far :

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse
,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private boolean paused = true;

URL url;
Bitmap bmImg = null;



public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

final String LOG = "ListActivity";

private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;
private FunDapter<Product> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.d_activity_list_d);


    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ListActivity.this));

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ListActivity.this, this);

     taskRead.execute("http://symphonyrecords.6te.net/product.php");
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    registerForContextMenu(lvProduct);


}//onCreate


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    final Product selectedProduct = adapter.getItem(info.position);
    Log.d(LOG, selectedProduct.name);

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuUpdate){
        Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("product", selectedProduct);
        startActivity(in);
    }


    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void  processFinish(String s) {
    productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.name;
        }
    });




    adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            ListActivity.this, productList, R.layout.d_layout_list_d, dict);


    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);

}












public void playAndPause(View view1){
    Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    ImageButton button = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.ivShare);
    int icon;

    if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        icon = R.drawable.ic_pause;
    }
    else {
        paused = true;
        icon = R.drawable.ic_play;
    }

    button.setImageDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), icon));

  }



}
```

(considering this codes if you have any better way for doing this , or an idea for getting the selected item I would be so grateful) .. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In your Adapter in getView method :*

```
        Product m =(Product) mDataItems.get(position);
    holder.playPause.setImageResource(m.getPlayPauseId());
    holder.playPause.setTag(position);
    holder.playPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Product m =(Product) mDataItems.get(pos);
                if (paused) {
                m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                paused=false;
                }else {
                 m.setPlayPauseId(R.drawable.ic_play);
                 paused = true;
                }
                FunDapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }


    });
```